# Handling "Windows Security" window with pywinauto

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pywinauto

I am writing a program to connect to the `Remote Desktop Connection` automatically. So, up untill now I was successfull in getting the application up and running and have the `Computer Name` written into the text box. Then, I am able to automatically click submit btn. Here is the code:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().start("mstsc.exe")

computerName = "computer_name"
password = "password"

app['Dialog']['Edit'].type_keys(computerName, with_spaces=True)
app['Dialog']['Connect'].click()
```

This is the window where all the aforementioned stuff is done:
 [image]

The next thing that pops-up after hitting `Connect` button is the `Windows Security`, where I need to input password (automatically). However, I am not sure, how should python identify the controls of that window and especially the `Password` text field:

[image]

So far I have tried to indetify it by its title, but unsuccessfully:

```
windowsSecurity = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title_re = r"Windows Security")
```

**---------------------------------**
**SOLUTION** **--------------------------------**

Just solved the issue using the following way. Firstly I identified what are the controls of the window that pops up, but before that, I am leaving some pause time for it to come on surface. Secondly, using the controls that I have identified, I send the keys and send click command. Here is the list of controls that I got by dlg.print_ctrl_ids()

`| | Edit - '' (L656, T323, R1100, B371) | | ['Surname, NameEdit', 'Edit'] | | child_window(auto_id="PasswordField_2", control_type="Edit") | | |`

```
computerName = "computer"
password = "password"
app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="uia")
app.start('mstsc.exe')

dlg = app.window(title_re="Remote Desktop Connection")
dlg['Edit'].type_keys(computerName)
dlg['Connect'].click()

time.sleep(5)

if dlg.child_window(title="Windows Security",control_type="Window").exists():

    windows_security = dlg.child_window(title="Windows     Security",control_type="Window")
    dlg['PasswordField_2'].type_keys(password)    
    dlg.child_window(auto_id='OkButton').click_input()
else:
    print("Wait time exceeded")
```

Comment: Please post your solution as answer and accept it. It's OK and it will show others the problem is solved.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I was looking exactly for that, just thought would look like the snake eating its own tail)) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just solved the issue using the following way. Firstly I identified what are the controls of the window that pops up, but before that, I am leaving some pause time for it to come on surface. Secondly, using the controls that I have identified, I send the keys and send click command. Here is the list of controls that I got by dlg.print_ctrl_ids()

`| | Edit - '' (L656, T323, R1100, B371) | | ['Surname, NameEdit', 'Edit'] | | child_window(auto_id="PasswordField_2", control_type="Edit") | | |`

```
computerName = "computer"
password = "password"
app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="uia")
app.start('mstsc.exe')

dlg = app.window(title_re="Remote Desktop Connection")
dlg['Edit'].type_keys(computerName)
dlg['Connect'].click()

time.sleep(5)

if dlg.child_window(title="Windows Security",control_type="Window").exists():

    windows_security = dlg.child_window(title="Windows         Security",control_type="Window")
    dlg['PasswordField_2'].type_keys(password)    
    dlg.child_window(auto_id='OkButton').click_input()
else:
    print("Wait time exceeded")
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using:

Import Desktop:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop
```

Then in the code:

```
windows_security = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Windows Security")
```

Found the solution in [this](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/940#issuecomment-893531689) GitHub issue.